# JSON array inside of an array

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am looking to access a string that is located inside of a JSON array that is located inside of another array. I am accessing the JSON API using JSONDecoder. I am receiving errors when trying the various methods that I have used in the past when using JSON arrays.

Here is the code:

```
var country = [Results]()

struct Rating: Codable {
    let results: [Results]
}

struct Results: Codable {
    let iso_3166_1: String
    let release_dates: [Release_Dates]
}

struct Release_Dates: Codable {
    let certification: String
}


func loadRating() {

    let id = filmId
    let apiKey = ""
    let url = URL(string: "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/\(id)/release_dates?api_key=\(apiKey)")
    let request = URLRequest(
        url: url! as URL,
        cachePolicy: URLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData,
        timeoutInterval: 10 )

    let session = URLSession (
        configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default,
        delegate: nil,
        delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main
    )

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (dataOrNil, response, error) in
        if let data = dataOrNil {
            do { let rates = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Rating.self, from: data)
               self.country = rates.results
                let us = self.country.filter({ $0.iso_3166_1.contains("US") })
                print(us)


        }
        }

    })

    task.resume()
}
```

`us` prints to console

`[Film.DetailsView.Results(iso_3166_1: "US", release_dates: [Film.DetailsView.Release_Dates(certification: "PG-13")])]`

I am trying to access the `certification` string.

What would be the correct method used to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`us` is an array of `Results`.

To get the first certification use this:

```
print(us.first!.release_dates.first!. certification)
```

I am force unwrapping for brevity, you should properly do it with optional binding or the guard statement.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty straightforward, the result of `filter` is an array and `certification` is in the array `release_dates`

```
let us = self.country.filter({ $0.iso_3166_1.contains("US") })
for item in us {
    for releaseDate in item.release_dates {
       print(releaseDate.certification)
    }
}
```

Please name your struct member names *lowerCamelCased* by mapping the keys with `CodingKeys` or with the `convertFromSnakeCase` strategy.

If there is only one `US` item, use `first`

```
if let us = self.country.first({ $0.iso_3166_1.contains("US") }) {
    for releaseDate in us.release_dates {
       print(releaseDate.certification)
    }
}
```