# JSON accessing multiple instances inside of an array

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift

I am using JSONDecoder to access JSON data through an API. Within this JSON Data are several `[arrays]`. I am running into a problem of accessing each instance that a key appears.

Here is the code:

```
var details = [Details]()
var production = [Production]()

struct Details: Codable {
    let title: String
    let poster_path: String?
    let id: Int?
    let production_companies: [Production]
}

struct Production: Codable {
    let name: String
}


let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (dataOrNil, response, error) in
        if let data = dataOrNil {
            do { let details = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Details.self, from: data)

let production = details.production_companies
print(production)

 }
        }

    })
```

Here is what `print(production)` prints to the console:

> [Film_Bee.DetailsView.Production(name: "Columbia Pictures"), Film_Bee.DetailsView.Production(name: "Marvel Entertainment"), Film_Bee.DetailsView.Production(name: "Sony Pictures")]

What I'm trying to do is access each `name` within the array. I know to access the first one I can use `production.first?.name` but if I am unsure how to access each one to place into a single label.

Comment: Do you want to add three companies' names into a single UIlabel or three UIlabel?

Comment: I'm wanting to put them into one label.

Comment: My answer to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52784393/json-array-inside-of-an-array) shows how to get all items in an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prashant points already. I just additionally add a little bit which may help you.

I believe you know swift loop like for or forEach to see your string list

```
production.forEach { model in
    print(model.name)
}
```

For your problem, you need to join your string list. As you need to update UI, use DispatchQueue.

```
let productionList = production.map{$0.name}
let strings = productionList.joined(separator: " ") //use "\n" if you wish new line
print("stringList: \(strings)")
DispatchQueue.main.async() {  
 yourLabel.text = strings
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`let production = details.production_companies.map{$0.name}`

What `production_companies` is Array. and you have to iterate over it using map and get its name that is simple to understand right ?

Not Related but don't use `try!` you should properly handle error use `do try catch block`